# react-native custom slider, using `diffClamp`

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

I have made a custom slider which can be seen [here.](https://snack.expo.io/4F6rGKMLi)

The problem is with the following snippet

```
let transX = cond(
  eq(gestureState, State.ACTIVE),
  diffClamp(add(offsetX, dragX), 0, 200),
  set(offsetX, add(offsetX, dragX)),
);
```

I am able to limit the range of the slider when the gesture is Active but I am not able to set the limit when the gesture has completed.

I tried adding `diffClamp` to the `set` method within the `cond`, but that fixes the position of the knob to the start and the whole slider behaves in a weird way.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been seeing some issues when trying to implement something similar using `diffClamp`, where `diffClamp` wouldn't assign the node in `set`. I would suggest implementing the `diffClamp` using `min` and `max`.

Something like this:

```
let transX = cond(
  eq(gestureState, State.ACTIVE),
  max(0, min(200, add(offsetX, dragX))),
  set(offsetX, max(0, min(200, add(offsetX, dragX)))),
);
```

Comment: I ended up redesigning the flow, but this is certainly a good shout. On further investigating, seems like `diffClamp` is stateful.